# Why isn't my ng-repeat working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, hybrid-mobile-app

I've tempted to do an ng-repeat that will retrieve card titles and place them into a list. Here is a section from my code that calls the content:

```html
<ion-content class="has-header" scroll="false" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="accordian">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3><span class="icon-dashboard" ng-repeat="card in cards"></span>Group 1</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">{{ card.title }}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Here is the controller:

```
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

// Card Array
$scope.data = {};
$scope.cards =[
{checked: false, title:'Bank', src:'img/bank.png',details:'Description will go here!'},
{checked: false, title:'BBVA', src:'img/bbva.png',details:'Description will go here!'},
{checked: false, title:'Nike', src:'img/nike.png',details:'Description will go here!'},
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code will repeat the `span` tag for each `card` that you have inside `cards`. I don't think that's what you intended to do. You probably want to repeat the `li`, right? Try this instead:

```
    <li ng-repeat="card in cards">
      <h3><span class="icon-dashboard"></span>Group 1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">{{ card.title }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Exactly this.  ng-repeat just repeats the tag it is specified on and all of it's contents.  In this case, you're repeating just the span for each of your cards.

Comment: Yeah placed it in the wrong place!However this is a JQuery Accordion list and when you open the list... it closes the list. Do you's know how to fix this?

Comment: @TheGarrett I'm afraid that's a completely different question. I would need to see more of your code in order to help you, a plunker or a jsFiddle would be nice too. However, keep in mind that the best way for integrating external plugins is to use custom directives.